# Problems with Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: python

Im making a Tic Tac Toe game but I have met a couple of problems while doing it.

The firs problem, is that when I had the board like:

```
 X | - | X
```

or like:

```
- | X | X
```

It counts as a Win and I don't know why. If I put:

```
X | X | -
```

there's no problem with that.

The second problem, is that I want to prevent the user to select a position that is already in use, so my idea is to add to a list the position that has been selected and compare if it is already in it or not. The problem is that when I call the function for the second time it doesn't have the previus list that contain the information of the previus position (it makes a new one), therefore it never detects that the position that the user is giving is already in use.

```
board = ["-","-","-",
           "-","-","-",
           "-","-","-"]

def display():

    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])

def turn():

    exist=[]

    pos = int(input("Choose your position"))

    while True:
        if pos not in exist:
            exist.append(pos)
            print(exist)
            print("Correct position")
            break

        else:
            print("That position has been selected, choose another one")

    board[pos-1] = "X"
    display()

def checkwin():
    #row
    if (board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == "X") or (board[3] and board[4] and board[5] == "X") or (board[6] and board[7] and board[8] == "X"):
        print("Victory")
        return False
    else:
        return True


display()
while checkwin():
    turn()
    checkwin()
    print(board)

print("Game has ended")
```

NOTE: Right now the game only can have the X player, I need still to add the O player. Also, it only can detect the win for the rows. Im still working on this.

Answer (score 3):

To your second question, you are declaring your list inside the function `turn`, which is called every time a player makes a choice. When a function returns, all of its local variables are no longer accessible. Compare this with your code.

```
def addToList( item ):
    items = []
    items.append( item )
addToList( 'item1' )
addToList( 'item2' )
```

Each time the function is called, `items = []`  is called as well. Edit to clarify my first statement, functions create their own scope. The scope of a variable is where it is available in your program. For example

```
def addItem( item ):
    items = []
    items.append( item )
addItem( "item1" )
print( items )
ERROR: items is not defined
```

Comment: I loved this explication, this was pretty helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of `(board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == "X")` won't work because you are only checking is `board[2] == 'X'`, the others are just truthy, thus `'-'` will also evaluate to `True`

You should rather check like this `(board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == "X")`.
This ensures that all values are equal to `'X'`

Comment: Note you can also check for either player winning with: `(board[0] == board[1] == board[2] and board[0] != "-")`.  It might be helpful to put all the index combinations to be tested into a list and use a loop to prevent excessive code duplication.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's totally understandable, thank you so much, guys. Do you know about my second issue? My fuction turn() doesn't append correcly

Answer (score 1):

sin tribu nailed it as to why your `turn` function is behaving the way it is.

As to how to make it work right... perhaps I'm missing something, but aren't you looking to make sure you can't select a space that's already occupied? For that, you could just check the board directly.

```py
def turn():
    pos = int(input("Choose your position"))

    while board[pos-1] == "X":
        pos = int(input("That position has been selected, choose another one"))
    
    print("Correct position")
    board[pos-1] = "X"
    display()
```

This will keep asking until you specify an empty square.

Comment: That's an interesting approach to solve the problem, thank you!